# Append column values from one column to another based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of connected values (edges and nodes). It shows how family and friends are connected and it looks like:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Orginal_Match | Orginal_Name | Connected_ID | Connected_Name | Connection_Type | Match-Final | ID_Match_0 | Name_Match_0 | ID_Match_1 | Name_Match_1 | ID_match_2 | Name_Match_2 | Connection_Type_0 | Connection_Type_1 | Connection_Type_2 |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|             1 | A            |            2 | B              | FRIEND          |           1 | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | NaN               | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            4 | E              | FAMILY          |           1 | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | NaN               | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            3 | F              | FRIEND          |           2 | 3          | C            | 11         | H            | 2          | B            | FRIEND            | FRIEND            | FRIEND            |
|             1 | A            |            5 | G              | FRIEND          |           2 | 4          | E            | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | FAMILY            | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            6 | D              | FRIEND          |           2 | 3          | C            | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | FRIEND            | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            7 | B              | FAMILY          |           2 | 2          | B            | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | FRIEND            | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            7 | B              | FRIEND          |           2 | 2          | B            | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | FRIEND            | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            8 | B              | FRIEND          |           2 | 2          | B            | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | FRIEND            | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |            9 | C              | OTHER           |           2 | 3          | C            | NaN        | NaN          | NaN        | NaN          | FRIEND            | NaN               | NaN               |
|             1 | A            |           10 | I              | FRIEND          |           3 | 3          | C            | 6          | D            | NaN        | NaN          | FRIEND            | FRIEND            | NaN               |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

In the above dataframe, `Original_Match` is connected to `Connected_ID` either directly or indirectly. `Match-Final` says how many other connections (nodes) are between them. Thus, if `Match-Final` is 1, `Original_Match` and `Connected_ID` are directly connected. For any value `x` in `Match-Final`, the number of connections (edges along a single path) between `Original_Match` and `Connected_ID` is `x-1` (that is the number of edges one must walk along to get from `Original_Match` to `Connected_ID` is equal to `Match-Final`; there can still be n nodes between each set of nodes, but they are all the same distance away). The `ID_Match_0` through `ID_Match_n` columns say all the IDs that were connected in between the previous node and the next node.

As a note for clarity, `Match-Final` only states the number of edges between the first and last node in the connection if you were walk along one path. It has no bearing on the amount of nodes at every connection. Therefore `Match-Final` could be 2, meaning that you would need to walk along two edges to get from `Orginal_Match` to `Connected_ID` but there could be n paths you could take to do so, because `Original_Match` may be connected to n nodes, which are then connected to `Connected_ID`. Thus they are still only two steps away from one another.

So for example, in the above dataframe, the data states that:

```
Row 0: Match-Final == 1, so Original_Match is connected directly to Connected_ID and they are connected via, Connection_Type. Therefore 

1A---FRIEND--2B

__________________________________________________________________________________________________

Row 2: Match-Final == 2, so Original_Match is connected to Connected_ID via ID_Match_0, ID_Match_1, ID_Match_2, using all the corresponding Connection_Type columns. Therefore 

 11H---------------------#
  |                      |
FRIEND                FRIEND
  |                      |
  1--FRIEND--3C--FRIEND--3F 
  |                      |
FRIEND                FRIEND
  |                      |
  2B---------------------#

_________________________________________________________________________________________

Row 9: Match-Final == 3, so Original_Match is connected to something, which is then connected to ID_Match_1, ID_Match_2, which then connects to Connected_ID. Therefore

1A--FRIEND--3C--FRIEND--10I
```

In order to make this a network graph, however, I need to transform the dataframe above into:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Orginal_Match | Orginal_Name | Connected_ID | Connected_Name | Connection_Type |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|             1 | A            |            2 | B              | FRIEND          |
|             1 | A            |            4 | E              | FAMILY          |
|             1 | A            |            3 | F              | FRIEND          |
|             1 | A            |            5 | G              | FRIEND          |
|             1 | A            |            6 | D              | FRIEND          |
|             1 | A            |            7 | B              | FAMILY          |
|             1 | A            |            7 | B              | FRIEND          |
|             1 | A            |            8 | B              | FRIEND          |
|             1 | A            |            9 | C              | OTHER           |
|             1 | A            |           10 | I              | FRIEND          |
|             3 | C            |            3 | F              | FRIEND          |
|            11 | H            |            3 | F              | FRIEND          |
|             2 | B            |            3 | F              | FRIEND          |
|             4 | E            |            5 | G              | FAMILY          |
|             3 | C            |            6 | D              | FRIEND          |
|             2 | B            |            7 | B              | FRIEND          |
|             2 | B            |            7 | B              | FRIEND          |
|             2 | B            |            8 | B              | FRIEND          |
|             3 | C            |            9 | C              | FRIEND          |
|             3 | C            |           10 | I              | FRIEND          |
|             6 | D            |           10 | I              | FRIEND          |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Which means that I need to append the values in `ID_Match_0,..., ID_Match_n` and `Name_Match_0,..., Name_Match_n` to `Original_Match` and `Connected_ID` based on where they match and the number in `Match-Final`. I also need to append the `Connection_Type_n` to `Connection_Type` via the same criteria.

This would need to be looped for n number of `ID_Match`, `Name_Match`, and `Connection_Type` columns.

I have considered using `np.where` but I haven't gotten anywhere with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: While this is an interesting problem, it's kinda hard to figure out your data. For example, why row `2` has 3 intermediate nodes but `MatchFinal==2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang there can be n intermediate nodes between one node and another. I am not sure if I explained that well. But what it's supposed to say is that the `Original_Match` is connected to n intermediate nodes (as in the example you stated), which are all connected to `Connected_ID`. So `Match-Final` states how many steps between `Original_Match` and `Connected_ID` there are. Hopefully the extra sentence in the edit clarifies that a bit.

Comment: That's what I understand from your statement.That is, if the `MatchFinal==2`, then there are 2 nodes between 'Original_Match` and `Connected_ID`. What I'm trying to say is your sample data does not align with the statement, which makes it harder for ppl to develop the code and test it on the data.

Comment: @QuangHoang I edited the question such that it should make sense as to what I am asking, now, if that helps.

Comment: Row 9 has `[1A, 9C, 3C]` nodes, **row 10** has `[1A, 10I, 3C, 6D]` nodes right? How did you get `1A--FRIEND--3C--FRIEND--10I` result for row 9 if it even does not contain 10I node? If you actually described it for row 10, than probably you missed one node. Could you please explain?